# Jquery value of checkbox always return on

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox and I tried the following:

```
var closedIssue = $('#closed-' + rowCounter).val();
```

but it always return 'on'

Here is the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="closed-' + rowCounter + '" id="closed-' + rowCounter + '" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var returnCheck = $('#closed-' + rowCounter).is(':checked');
```

will return you current status of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [`checked` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) using the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead. It will return a boolean.

```
var closedIssue = $('#closed-' + rowCounter).prop('checked');
```

Or plain JavaScript:

```
var closedIssue = document.getElementById('closed-' + rowCounter).checked;
```